error component is not defined when using child tag in vue instance
I've just started to learn vuejs and I've tried to run a little code applying what I've learned by creating a basic component inside the vue instance using Vue.component('nameOfComponent', { });, yet nothing is displayed and I got Uncaught ReferenceError: HelloWorld is not defined
What's the fault in the following code ?
<html>
<head>
<head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.16/dist/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <HelloWorld @updated="fct" :numb="firstNumb"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
Vue.component('HelloWorld', { 
  template:'<h1 @click="mymeth">{{" click to increase !}}{{ numb }}</h1>',
  props: {
    numb: Number
  },
  methods:{
    mymeth(){
     this.$emit('updated', this.numb+1);
    console.log("value firstNumb in child component ", this.numb)
    },
  }
});
new Vue({
 'el':'#app',
 data:{
      firstNumb:5,
},
components: { HelloWorld },

 methods:{
     fct(e){
    this.firstNumb=e;
    console.log("value firstNumb in parent component ", this.firstNumb)
    },
 
 }
 });
 
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>


It should be noted off the bat that Vue 2 has reached EOL (end of life) and you should be learning Vue 3 if anything.  Regardless, to your question...
The component needs to be assigned to a variable to be properly referenced within new Vue()
const HelloWorld = Vue.component(...)

new Vue({
  ...
  components: { HelloWorld },
  ...
})

Also when adding custom elements directly in the DOM you must use kebab-case as noted in the Vue 2 documentation:

only kebab-case names are valid directly in the DOM

<div id="app">
  <hello-world @updated="fct" :numb="firstNumb"/>
</div>

Correcting a few other minor mistakes/typos, the working code then is provided below:


<html>
<head>
<head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.16/dist/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <hello-world @updated="fct" :numb="firstNumb"/>
</div>
<script>

const HelloWorld = Vue.component('HelloWorld',{
  template:'<h1 @click="mymeth">click to increase ! {{ numb }}</h1>',
  props: {
    numb: Number
  },
  methods:{
    mymeth(){
      this.$emit('updated', this.numb+1);
      console.log("value firstNumb in child component ", this.numb)
    },
  }
});

new Vue({
  el : '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      firstNumb: 5
    }
  },
  components: { HelloWorld },
  methods:{
    fct(e){
      this.firstNumb=e;
      console.log("value firstNumb in parent component ", this.firstNumb)
    },
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>




components: { HelloWorld } isn't needed because Vue.component registers HelloWorld
globally, it's either one or another

by "adding custom elements directly in the DOM" you mean component creation using Vue.component right ?
else for this note "The component needs to be assigned to a variable to be properly referenced within new Vue()" in some youtube tutorials Vue.component(...) was used just like what I did, I wonder how it worked for them

yes, see Estus' comment.  I don't use Vue without a build step that often so I was unaware of the fact it's registered globally.  Perhaps only the kebab correction was needed in this case.

ok, but why the value in the child displays value less than 1 compared to parent ? (exp: value firstNumb in parent component  6 VS value firstNumb in child component  5) it is supposed that the child is also 6 after emitting this.numb+1 and the update in the parent, am I wrong ?

console logs only show the value at a specific point in time.  after the emit, you console log immediately. It takes slightly longer to capture the event in the parent, set new value, then update the prop back in the child.  the fact that the UI shows 6, which is displayed in the child, we know the prop value is in fact getting updated.

since that takes slightly longer, I think if I settimeout until the update is done I would get the good display ?

it's not a problem with your app, it's a problem in how you're trying to debug.  it is not a good practice to add timeouts to your code just for logging purposes.  it is better to debug reactive variables by verifying their values in the template (which you already are),  using something like a watcher that can log the moment a change in value is detected, or using more advanced debugging tools such as vue devtools
